# How to convert json checked checkbox data to a list?

Tags: php, json, checkbox

How would I convert a json string that contains checkbox values to a list?

For example, I have the following json string :
{"User1":"Checked","User2":"","User3":"Checked"}

I want to pull a list from the above data, and assign it to a variable.  The list should of course, only output the checked elements as such :

User1
User3

and ignore the unchecked items.

Is this possible?

Original thought was to do this in a jqgrid layout, original question here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615244/best-way-to-do-jqgrid-with-json-strings

Full Array Code(processing side) :

```
$status = $data['data-invoice-status']; // this is an array
                $status_array = array(); // create new array
                $status_names = array(1 => "Service Call",2 => "Estimate",3 => "Bid Accepted",4 => "Unstaged",5 => "Staged",6 => "Assigned",7 => "In Progress",8 => "Job Complete",9 => "Billed");
                for($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++){ // loop from 1 to 5
                if(in_array($i, $status)){ // if value exists (has been selected), stack 'checked', if not, stack ''.
                    $status_array[$status_names[$i]] = "checked";
                } else {
                    $status_array[$status_names[$i]] = "";
                }
                }
                $status_json = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con, json_encode($status_array)); // encode the array into JSON and then escape it.
```

I then save $statusd into my db whenever anyone updates the form, but no data is transferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decode the JSON to an array, then get the keys where the value equals 'Checked':

```
$list = array_keys(json_decode($json, true), 'Checked');
```

Or possibly to filter out empty items instead of searching for 'Checked', but then you still have keys instead of values:

```
$list = array_filter(json_decode($json, true));
```

Then `implode()` or `foreach()` or whatever to work with the array.

### Based on your edits:

1. You really should use a related table and save each user to a new row, but
2. You're encoding then adding slashes `mysqli_real_escape_string` and then trying to decode it again

Assuming you're not going to do #1 then just this:

```
$statusd = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->_con,
                                     implode(",",  array_keys($status_array, 'Checked')));
```

Comment: okay, I tried your code, multiple ways and cannot get to work.  This is what I am trying to do, I do not know how to translate my {"User1":"checked","User2":""} into a jqgrid that is programmed via a link I will add in my question, so I thought of just pointing it to a normal output sql(this question)  If there is a way of making work with jqgrid, that would be my preference, but from a LAIC(look at it crooked) standpoint, so would this. (sorry about the spiel)

Comment: I tried the following code :$statusa = array_keys(json_decode($status_json, true));
    $statusd = implode(",", $statusa); and it returns null and does not save?

Comment: You'll need to update your question with more detail and exactly want you want the output to be.

Comment: added updated code to question.  Any specific detail you are looking for?

Comment: That saved a value called "checked", but nothing else.  I will add my array code if that helps

Comment: Thank You, Thank You, THANK YOU!

Comment: I use jqgrid, and it saves each user to a new row for me